# Is it possible to make a Guzzle request to an endpoint that has CORS restriction to one domain origin?

Tags: php, web-scraping, cors, guzzle

I'm trying to get some data from an endpoint. And the endpoint allows only requests that originate from one specific domain (which is not mine)

Is it possible to make a request with Guzzle and make it "pretend" as if it was coming from the allowed origin?

Currently I am trying to set some headers to achieve that and get the response back but it is always returning me code 200 with content-length: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Origin` header to what you want as long as you are making a request out of browser's control. In Guzzle it could be set like this:

```
$client->request('GET', '/data', [
    'headers' => [
        'Origin' => 'http://foo.bar',
    ]
]);
```

If targeting host is satisfied with this only header then you are fine otherwise you won't get your expected response.

Comment: okay so even if server is asking for some form data, cookies, headers etc it can all be "faked" through Guzzle, correct?

Comment: Guzzle mainly is a CURL wrapper, so whatever you do with CURL you can  do with Guzzle. You can send every thing you need with it. @GladToHelp